# Two job titles in one job

Tags: resume, career-development, job-description, title

My last job was as an Assitant IT-Manager, but I also worked with cloud services like azure & AWS in the same job. I am also pursuing certifications in above mentioned cloud providers.

So can I write in my resume about this both job titles? For example

> Assistant I.T Manager & Cloud Engineer (All Warehouses & Branches),
>   Imtiaz Super Market

Comment: State the title and what you did.  If the latter is more than the title warrants then be more explicit.

Comment: What’s you’re official job title? You only listed one job title but you’re asking for two. Why? Cloud Engineer sounds like something you just made up.

Answer (score 4):

Resumes aren't fixed. When you are applying for a job that requires management experience feature the Assistant I.T. Manager aspect of the job. For ones where they want cloud experience then feature Cloud engineer part of the job.

The title on a resume is both meaningless and important.  It is meaningless because there is no international database that compares title and companies in a ranking system. So the title mid-level software developer for company X can't be compared to senior Java programmer for company Y.  They are also important because people and computers sometimes scan looking for keywords, and the title is a place that a keyword may appear.

If you are going to tailor the resume for the job you are applying for, then make sure the descriptions and tile work to your best advantage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just want to know that since "Assistant IT Manager" doesn't describe the job description or what you do, so wouldn't it be good to tell something extra in job title?

Answer (score 1):

Use the title your previous employer gave you, otherwise when the recruiter calls the previous employer for a reference and ask 'and did Daraz work in the role of Cloud Engineer' and they say 'no', you've been caught in a falsehood. It might be a small one, but it sets a question in the recruiter's mind. Also, if they employ a background check, the mismatch can result in a failure to pass the check.

If you want to highlight your work with cloud engineering,  outline the work you did in that role under your title (suitably targeted to the role you are applying to, of course).